# MODX3 manager sessions expiry frequently

Tags: php, timezone, modx-revolution

We have a MODX3 website with 2 editors. I don't have any issues myself but when my friend uses Manager, he will automatically be logged out a few times in an hour and he needs to re-login. The issue occurs only when he is using a certain laptop.

I checked the logs and made an interesting remark.

My log entries are using the UTC timezone (server timezone). This is how I want it to be.
My friend's log entries use the Finnish timezone. So the log's timestamps look like this:

- [2023-05-05 09:33:54] (UTC)
- [2023-05-05 12:34:48] (Finnish time)
- [2023-05-05 12:35:52] (Finnish time)
- [2023-05-05 12:36:36] (Finnish time)
- [2023-05-05 12:37:22] (Finnish time)
- [2023-05-05 09:37:22] (UTC)
- [2023-05-05 09:37:23] (UTC)

I was thinking that the timezone issue may affect sessions too and they, for some reason, expire.

Any ideas on how to debug the case more? How can I make sure all log entries are in the same timezone? I already set the MODX timezone setting to UTC but the issue seems to continue.

Comment: It seems that frequent session expiring is related to CDN. When I skip the CDN for Manager's use, the problem disappears. I still don't know, why the log entries use different timezone when I access Manager via CDN and why sessions expire fast.